# Possible bad audit - Triage: "Why Should I Write Unit Tests [...]"

Tags: support, disputed-review-audits, triage

I just went to fail with the following audit in **Triage**,

> *[Why Should I Write Unit Tests if I have UI Automation Tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51869677/why-should-i-write-unit-tests-if-i-have-ui-automation-tests)* 
>   *[Triage Review link](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/20800221)*

I should have review it positively, but I did not (I flagged it as *"Off-topic"*).

This question has a good score, as its answers, and is related to IT. Seeing the actual question I would not even touch it.

But seeing it from the review, it just looks like an off-topic question. The 1st comment is:

> This question is more suited to the Software Engineering community than Stack Overflow

Which I agree with *(but according to the second comment this would be a downvoted duplicate. Maybe this question should not have been asked)*.

This question is *"clear and answerable"*, but if it was posted recently I would still think it belongs on another Stack Exchange site and flag it.

Am I wrong about *"Off-topic"* or is it a *"bad audit"*?

Comment: Two things: 1) Just because a question is more suited to another site does not mean it's off-topic here, as a heads up. 2) What reason did you flag it off-topic for? Just _"Off-topic"_ doesn't narrow it down much..

Comment: @Kendra I would have flagged as belonging to another stack exchange site but Software Engineering isn't in the list. I chose "balantly off-topic" which is then a bit too much I agree.

Comment: @gnat In this case, if the question _is_ on-topic as it appears at first glance to be, this question won't be answered there- It's not a faulty audit, in that case, it's just a user misunderstanding what they should have done and trying to learn how to review better.

Comment: @gnat It's a bit early to close this specific disputed audit with a general reasons why audits might incorrectly fail. I think there's room to discuss this specific case, that's what the [meta-tag:disputed-review-audits] tag is for.

Comment: In terms of flagging for migration, so many people incorrectly sent posts to Software Engineering that it _had_ to be removed to keep from flooding them with low quality or off-topic posts. For the most part, if the migration path isn't on the list, you should use a custom mod flag. _However,_ if you're not a user of that site, and haven't been there for a while, the mods will likely not migrate the post. So, in this case, skipping really would've been your best bet.

Comment: @Kendra thanks I'll skip this kind of question next time, then.

Comment: What do you mean by *"IT"*? IT excludes software development.

Comment: @PeterMortensen That depends on where you're from- In my locale, IT _100%_ includes software development.

Comment: In some ways this is a really good audit because it dispels the incorrect assumption that questions that might have a better home on another SE network are always off-topic on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @ryanyuyu should users be potentially banned for an audit question like this though? Seems a bit unfair. I'm more likely to just click skip on questions like this because I don't want to risk it and because so many people have different opinions on questions like this.